# How to align fields with text inside of a heading

Tags: html, css

This is reduction of a simple page I am working on. I am trying to align the image, User Name, Password and Sign in button with the E from Enter.  No matter what I do they are sticking to the left of the page and not budging.  Do I need to tie them to the Enter with a special align?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>


<style>
.text-box {
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  position: center;
}


.btn {
 font-size: 14px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
</style>
```

```
 <img src="" width="200" height="300"/>
  <div class="login-header">
    
    <h2 id="title" align="center">
    Enter   
    &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
    Test
    </h2>
      <br>
  </div>

  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
    <div class="form-group text-box" align="center">
          
     <label for="name">User Name*</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-box">
      <label for="name">Password*</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
    
      <button
      type="submit"
      id="btn-login"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-block button">
        Sign In
    </button>
    <br>
    
    <hr>
  
  </form>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't really clear, I have no idea what you mean by "align with the E"

Comment: The word Enter is in the heading up on top of the page.  The E in Enter

Comment: Yes, what do you mean by that? What do you mean align them with a single letter in a div and not the whole thing? could you sketch out what you want it to do?

Comment: The left side of the text boxes and button should line up on the same up-down line as the E in Enter.

Comment: You can actually present working code that people will more likely be able to understand if you look closely at the StackOverFlow editor options.  Short of that make a link to a JsBin or other cloud IDE.

Comment: Please post **runnable** code here instead of static one, so we could see how it *renders*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot I had to change, as your layout is honestly not very well written, it seems like you are learning to write HTML from a very old guide (I'm guessing W3). You shouldn't be using things like `<br>` or `&nbsp;` The sooner you can start seeing styling as blocks and not the alignment of text like in a word document, the better.

but what I did here was remove the formatting from your header, left aligned it, then gave both it and your form a fixed width and automatic margin:

```css
.text-box {
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  position: center;
}

.btn {
 font-size: 14px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

#title{
  margin: auto;
  width:250px;
}

form{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
 <img src="" width="200" height="300"/>
  <div class="login-header">
    
    <h2 id="title">
    Enter
    </h2>
      <br>
  </div>

  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
    <div class="form-group text-box" align="center">
          
     <label for="name">User Name*</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-box">
      <label for="name">Password*</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
    
      <button
      type="submit"
      id="btn-login"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-block button">
        Sign In
    </button>
    <br>
    
    <hr>
  
  </form>
```

However that isn't what I would recommend doing, you should put the header IN the form. Like so, then format the form the same as before.

```css
.text-box {
  text-align: left;
  width: 300px;
  position: center;
}

.btn {
 font-size: 14px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

form{
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
 <img src="" width="200" height="300"/>

  <form onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
    <h2 id="title">
    Enter
    </h2>
    <div class="form-group text-box" align="center">
          
     <label for="name">User Name*</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        class="form-control"
        id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-box">
      <label for="name">Password*</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        class="form-control"
        id="password"
        placeholder="Enter your password">
    </div>
    
      <button
      type="submit"
      id="btn-login"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-block button">
        Sign In
    </button>
    <br>
    
    <hr>
  
  </form>
```

Comment: That's great!  Is there simple adjustment to put the word Test on the same line as Enter?  That would mean pulling Enter (and the stuff below it) back to the left just a bit.

Comment: Oh I see you took the word Test out!  Yeah that should be the right half of the Enter part.

Comment: @John I took it out because the way it was formatted was very wrong, I'm writing up how you would put that in now, do you intend to have a form below test as well?

Comment: Just some text.  So yeah something.

Comment: That looks terrific!  btw if I wanted to move the image to Enter as well?  It's an empty link now but I would left align it with Enter...

Comment: @John You still want it to be above enter?

Comment: Thanks!  One last thing...if I wanted to move the Enter and Test stuff down to the center of the page.  And if a line cut the screen into two equal halves on left and right, the Enter and Test sections would be on either side of it in the center of the screen.

Comment: @John I don't think I understand the question

Comment: Yes if possible  re: the image above Enter

Comment: Right now,  Enter and Test are at the very top of the screen.  Could they be in the center?

Comment: @John I suggest doing your own research on this stuff. Google things like "Center element vertically." It is all very well covered

Comment: @John Check the codepen for my final edit